# How do I get the value out of a Future in Scalaz?

Tags: scala, future, scalaz

I've got the following code:

```
package functorapplication

import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import scalaz.concurrent.Future

object FunctorApplication2 extends App {

  val f1 = Future(3)//(ec)
  val f2 = Future(4)//(ec)
  val f3 = Future(5)//(ec)
  val calculate = (a: Int) => (b: Int) => (c: Int) => a + b + c
  val area = f1 <*> (f2 <*> (f3 <*> Future(calculate)))//(ec))) // Future(12)

  //println(area)//BindSuspend(scalaz.concurrent.Future$$Lambda...
  println("starting")
  val summed = for {
    a <- area
  } yield {
    println(a)
  }
  area.map(value => println(value))

  //println(summed)//Suspend(scalaz.concurrent.Future$$Lambda...
  println("done")

}
```

This gives the following result:

```
starting
done
```

The point being - there appears to be no value in the future that is in the for comprehension or being mapped over.

My question is: **How do I get the value out of a Future in Scalaz?**

Notes:

This is my scala version

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.5",
```

This is my scalaz version

```
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.26",
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-concurrent" % "7.2.26",
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-effect" % "7.2.26",
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-iteratee" % "7.2.26"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you hold a value of type `Future[A]`, then you are eligible to obtain at some time in the future

- either a value of type `A`
- or instead an error, represented as a value of type `Throwable`.

So, a future represents a potential future value. The only known way to obtain a future value is to **Await** it.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val f1 = Future(3)//(ec)
val f2 = Future(4)//(ec)
val f3 = Future(5)//(ec)

val calculate = (a: Int) => (b: Int) => (c: Int) => a + b + c

val area: Future[Int] = for {
  v1 <- f1 
  v2 <- f2 
  v3 <-f3 
} yield calculate(v1)(v2)(v3)

println("starting")

println("adding future side effect")
//this happens in the future
val withSideEffect = area.map(value => println("side-effect: " + value))

println("awaiting now")
//now, let's wait
println("Await: " + Await.ready(withSideEffect, Duration.Inf).value)

println("done")
```

This prints:

```
starting
adding future side effect
awaiting now
side-effect: 12
Await: Some(Success(()))
done
```